# ForEach Loop Container does not pass variables to DataFlowTask

Tags: variables, ssis, oledb

I have ForEach Loop Container (FEL Container) with DataFlowTask (DFT) in my SSIS. In DFT there is OLE DB SRC with SQL Comand coming from variable "DateToSelect" . This variable have two parameters - StartDate & EndDate, which I pass in my FELC Container. The goal of SSiS is to load table on SQL Server for certain periods

Problem is the next - SSIS runs without errors - but information do not load in table. I have put Breakpoints and Watches to see either my variables are changing - and they really do, but still nothing is loading.

Have somebody ideas what is wrong?

[image]

[image]

I have mentioned one more detail - package downloads data only for april, while period is from january to april (or from february to april) and if I change period from january to march - again no data is downloading..

Comment: Post screenshots of all the places where you use the variables.

Comment: Done! Two screens - ForEach Loop Container , DataFlowTask

Comment: Thanks everybody for attention, I have found what was the problem - simply EventHandler that was changing my period inside LoopContainer!